# How do I stop my Magento Theme Overriding Instant Search

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have been setting up a Magento 1.9 site and using the excellent free Instant Search extension from Magestore.

After installing a new Theme, the Instant Search has since stopped working.

Is there an easy way to set the "weight" of extensions so they are not overridden by others?

Or does anyone know how I could make the Magestore Instant Search work with Ultimo theme?

Comment: Have you placed layout (.xml) and template (.phtml) files in ultimo theme?

Comment: Hi Mohit, I haven't put any files in the ultimo theme folders (Sorry I'm a Magento novice!)

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put layout and template files of **Instant Search extension** into **layout** and **template** folders respectively.

For instance:

- Put layout file(s) of Instant Search extension into **app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout** folder.
- Put template file(s) of Instant Search extension into **app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template** folder.

Please let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi Mohit, i have done the above and the search is now working again! Thanks so much for you guidance.

Comment: glad to know that I could help you :)